# How to create vector graphic image like these?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, images, corel-draw

Would anybody please do let me know how to create graphic images/ effects as mentioned in below images?

I want to know the `tools/ techniques` to create such graphics images for web based usage.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wellcone to GD.se. Could you be a bit more specific, i mean ellipses, circles and rounded rectangles should be easy to make, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create these illustrations using almost any graphic software.

Adobe [**Illustrator**](http://www.adobe.com/nz/products/illustrator.html) and Adobe [Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/nz/products/photoshop.html) are both paid (subscription based, you can try them for free for a month) and can work with vectors. Illustrator is the preferred choice for creating scalable graphics.

If you are looking for free alternatives, then [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/en/) is probably your best choice, as it's developed to work with vectors. [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) is another open source program, but better for raster images.

Regarding the techniques to make the drawings, you'd have to draw the shapes yourself and then use a combination of filled backgrounds (for the filled clouds and atom) and strokes (for all the lines).

The result will depend on how much practise you have making illustrations, these are not difficult technically, but still very hard to master.